# Using Random() with a Bias

Tags: javascript, random

Suppose I have an array

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

and I want to select one value from `List` at random. If it is completely random, each will have a 25% chance. Is there a way to select a value at random with a bias like so:

```
var bias = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6];
```

(bias of course adds up to 1)

So 'a' has a 10% chance of being selected and 'b' has a 20% chance of being selected, etc

Edit: I know I can just modify do `var list = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd']` and just select a value at random but I am looking for a more efficient way of doing this by just having an array that contains the bias.

Comment: Unless your list gets really large, (which depends on the exact requirements, such as if you want something to be picked 2.3486% of the time) I suspect that your quick and dirty way is "more efficient" than the answers below which require summing things and their own array of floats.

Comment: @user949300: The cumulative bias array is nice if you need to pull several samples from the same list with same probabilities, so you can (and should) precalculate it. It is not *required*: you can just go summing-and-sequentially-searching every time you need a sample if the biases change all the time, or just want to do it once (however, then you can't use binary search). It is also the only way to do it if biases are not all integral multiples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a cumulative bias list:

```
var sum = 0;
var cumulativeBias = bias.map(function(x) { sum += x; return sum; });
```

Then make a random number from `0` to the `sum` (i.e. `cumulativeBias[cumulativeBias.length - 1]`):

```
var choice = Math.random() * sum;
```

Then search for the first element in `cumulativeBias` that is bigger than `choice`. You can use binary search for speed, but for short lists a sequential search is good enough. The index of that element is the chosen index. For example, something like:

```
var chosenIndex = null;
cumulativeBias.some(function(el, i) {
    return el > choice ? ((chosenIndex = i), true) : false;
});
chosenElement = list[chosenIndex];
```

Comment: For this few elements, it's not a big deal, but the ES5 `Array.reduce` will make this a bit faster: `var cumulativeBias = bias.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b });`

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler: Ooh, forgot about that, thanks!

Comment: Oh, actually, I'm wrong Amadan.  You need the whole array the way you're doing it, not just the final sum.  My bad. =)

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler—if speed is an issue, I'll bet a plain for loop is faster than the Array methods. But I doubt it's an issue. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I have written this in the past in the following way:

Replace your bias with a running total - i.e. add bias[0] to bias[1], then add bias[1] to bias[2], then add bias[2] to bias[3].

In your above example, you would get `var bias = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0]` - the last one should always be 1, otherwise you have done something wrong.

Now pick a random number between 0 and 1.0; find the largest number in the bias array, that is smaller than your random number. Pick the corresponding value from your list array.

Edit: @Amadan is right. I meant, find the smallest number in the bias array, that is larger than your random number. My "smallest" and "largest" were the wrong way round :)

Comment: 1) Funny name! :D 2) "largest number... that is smaller than random number" is not correct unless your running total list starts with `0`. 3) As long as you adjust the random number range, it doesn't matter what the sum is - your biases could be `[1, 4, 1, 1, 10]` and it will still work.

Comment: Last doesn't need to be one, it just sets the limit of the range so random is between 0 and limit. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: My statement that the bias should be 1 is based on the equivalent line in the question: `bias of course adds up to 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your bias is simple, you can just make an array that offers 10% `'a'`, 20% `'b'` and so on like this and then just pick a random value from that:

```
var choices = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'];
var biasVal = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
```

The choices array could be built programmatically if needed.  It would only have to be built once and from then on the selection of random choices would be significantly faster with this method.

Comment: I already posted that I did not want to use this method in the main post.

Comment: @Bijan - OK, didn't see that part of the post.  But this method would be faster and more efficient at runtime (e.g. each time you select a random choice) than any of the other methods which is something you said you wanted.